# Image import not working in Chrome works on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm a real JavaScript or jQuery illiterate and was just trying to troubleshoot a previously created functionality. This works on Firefox but fails on Chrome.I import an image and then crop the data required from it but sometimes the image is not clear and is very small so i need to give in a zoom functionality, then because the zoom concentrates on the centre of the image i need to give a move option that moves the image left or right, moving and zooming was possible with img tag alone so i used it and it worked well on firefox without any bugs, but the image isnt displayed at all in chrome, below there is the chunk of code that is related to importing an image and creating a canvas of it.  The previous developer had used the div tag to create a canvas, but zoom and move didnt work on the div tag for me.
 please ask if other details are required.

```
$("#movingImage").empty();
//$("#movingImage").attr("src", image.src);
$("#movingImage").append("<canvas id=\"canvas\">");
canvas = $("#canvas")[0];
context = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = image.width;
canvas.height = image.height;
context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
```

The HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="views" >   
<img src="" id="movingImage" alt="" />  
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Vijay, welcome to SO! Please take a look at the documentation on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I invite you to show a more detailed description of the error occurring in chrome.

Comment: "works on firefox but fails on chrome" does not provide a suitable detail. Please describe the problem in greater detail and include any relevant error messages (check the console for errors).

Answer (score 0):

The `append()` method inserts the given element as a child of the target. Yet an `img` tag cannot have a child. Maybe try [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) instead ?

For the same reason, not sure if the `empty()` method works here...

You can also try the [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) method to replace your `img` node with your created canvas

Comment: That's some good info u gave me Tibo, now the functionality works but the whole page is a mess because the function runs 5 times in all , each time showing a new image , now because the "empty" method does'nt work, the first image shows up 5 times , the second 4 , the third 3 and so on... Is there any way this can be achieved , is there an alternative to empty method?

Comment: Did you try the `replaceWith()` ? Instead of the `empty`, maybe you can use the [`remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) method

Comment: "replaceWith()" gives a distorted image after crop, so i used "after" which works well but as empty doesnt work, image repeats, "remove" isnt working as well.but if this is the issue how come firefox handles this page well and all functionalities are executed?